# Rails 4 Convert polymorphic type to different parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I am currently implementing functionality that has a model named "Conversation" which has many "messages" using a polymorphic association.

My goal is to create a new object from my "Feature" model from some of the fields on the "Conversation" object and attach all of the associated messages to Feature type "messages" I know I can just create the objects on the fly but if there is a simple way to change the "messageable_type" and associate the record with the Feature model that would be preferable.

My messageable polymorphic association is currently working properly on both my "Conversation" and "Feature" models.

**My Message Model:**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :messageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**My Conversation Model:**

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages, as: :messageable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :stakeholders, as: :stakeholderable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stakeholders, :messages
end
```

**My Feature Model:**

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stakeholders, as: :stakeholderable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :messages, as: :messageable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stakeholders, :messages
end
```

Comment: Can you give more context? It's hard for me to understand where/how you want to create the associated records

Comment: Hey Rich, thanks for trying to help.

Basically I want to be able to move the messages that are attached to my Conversation model to my Feature model. The more I look at it though it seems like I may be better off recreating the message objects on the feature model using feature.build_messages